# Hiding output of a command

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a script where it checks whether a package is installed or not and whether the port 8080 is being used by a particular process or not. I am not experienced at all with bash, so I did something like this:

```
if dpkg -s net-tools; then
    if  netstat -tlpn | grep 8080 | grep java; then
        echo "Shut down server before executing this script"
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "If the server is running please shut it down before continuing with the execution of this script"
fi

# the rest of the script...
```

However when the script is executed I get both the `dpkg -s net-tools` and the `netstat -tlpn | grep 8080 | grep java` outputs in the terminal, and I don't want that, how can I hide the output and just stick with the result of the `if`s?

Also, is there a more elegant way to do what I'm doing? And is there a more elegant way to know **what** process is using the port 8080 (not just if it's being used), if any?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

To hide the output of any command usually the **`stdout`** and **`stderr`** are redirected to [`/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Explanation:**

1.**`command > /dev/null`**: redirects the output of `command`(stdout) to `/dev/null`
2.**`2>&1`**: redirects `stderr` to `stdout`, so errors (if any) also goes to `/dev/null`

**Note**

**`&>/dev/null`**: redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`. one can use it as an alternate of `/dev/null 2>&1`

**Silent `grep`**: `grep -q "string"` match the string silently or quietly without anything to standard output. It also can be used to hide the output.

In your case, you can use it like,

```
if dpkg -s net-tools > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    if  netstat -tlpn | grep 8080 | grep java > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    #rest thing
else
    echo "your message"
fi
```

Here the if conditions will be checked as it was before but there will not be any output.

**Reply to the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474556/hiding-output-of-a-command/474566?noredirect=1#comment629333_474566)**:

`netstat -tlpn | grep 8080 | grep java > /dev/null 2>&1`: It is redirecting the output raised from `grep java` after the second pipe. But the message you are getting from `netstat -tlpn`. The solution is use second `if` as,

```
if  [[ `netstat -tlpn | grep 8080 | grep java` ]] &>/dev/null; then
```

Comment: You could also mention `grep -q`, and the newer bash `&> ...` as a synonym for `> ... 2>&1`

Comment: thank you, that enhaced the script. But I still get a message saying that some processes can't be shown since it's not being executed as root. This happens with `netstat`. Is there any way I could hide that too?

Comment: Regarding "*`grep -q "string"` [...] also can be used to hide the output*": while it hides *stdout* output, it does not hide *stderr* "output". E.g. `(echo "string via stdout"; echo "string via stderr" >&2) | grep -q "string"` "leaks" `string via stderr` on *stderr*. This may or may not be desirable. To hide *stderr* output, **including those originating from *grep* itself**: `((echo "string via stdout"; echo "string via stderr" >&2) | grep -q "string") 2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 3):

While flushing the output to `/dev/null` is probably the easiest way, sometimes `/dev/null` has file permissions set so that non-root cannot flush the output there. So, another non-root way to do this is by

```
command | grep -m 1 -o "abc" | grep -o "123"
```

This double-`grep` setup finds the matching lines with `abc` in them and since `-o` is set ONLY `abc` is printed and only once because of `-m 1`. Then the output which is either empty or `abc` is sent to grep to find only the parts of the string which match `123` and since the last command only outputs `abc` the empty string is returned. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

`lsof -i :<portnumnber>` should be able to do something along the lines of what you want.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the real question to the post, check it agin please because you answer is just for the "secondary" questions

Comment: also is there I way I could extract the process name/PID from the output of that command?

Comment: Another way to do the same thing is `fuser -n tcp 8080`, whose output may be easier to parse.